# How to get the last part of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the back part of a string when the string length is unknown?

> Hello World

i need

> World.

or

> Hello World the weather is fine.

i need

```
weather is fine
```

How to split it?

Comment: You first need to define in very clear terms what the "last part of the string" is. The examples you give provide no clear pattern to determine how to split the string. You seem to just want to split them at arbitrary points.

Comment: You have to know *where* to split, otherwise how would you know what to get? To split on space you just do `split(" ")`, but in the first one it's just the last item, the second one would be everything after the second space, which is different

Comment: We need more information about what you define as the 'last part of the string'. The first example is split at the last space, the second example at the third from last.

Comment: in the first string, where do you get the dot from?

Comment: Ask yourself - how do you know where to split? Once you know where to split, count the number of chars to that point and then perform a `substr` or `split` if you know the separator string / character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ws='Hello World'
var w='Hello World the weather is fine.'
var ss=w.split(ws);
for(i=0;i<ss.length;i++){
   if(ss[i].length>0)
   console.log(ss[i]);
}
```

Comment: Even ignoring the 'code dump' answer, it doesn't match the OP's specifications

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers